# Insert to database multiple options from HTML form via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have drop-down list, after selecting any value It adding new row with some fields, example shown in image below:

[image: drop-down list]

I have insert.php to insert values to *MySQL* database. But there is problem, that only values from first row are inserted to database.

**PHP looks like:**

```
foreach($_POST['CertificateType'] as $key => $val){ 

    $CertificateType = $val;

    $CertificateType = $_POST['CertificateType'][$key]; 
    $STCWCode        = $_POST['STCWCode'][$key];            
    $CertNo          = $_POST['CertNo'][$key];          
    $FromCert        = $_POST['FromCert'][$key];            
    $ToCert          = $_POST['ToCert'][$key];  

    $CertificateType = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $CertificateType);  
    $STCWCode        = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $STCWCode);                 
    $CertNo          = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $CertNo);           
    $FromCert        = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $FromCert);                 
    $ToCert          = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $ToCert);      

    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO Tbl (
        CertificateType     
        ,UserId    
        ,STCWCode               
        ,CertNo                 
        ,FromCert               
        ,ToCert
        ,DateCreated
    ) VALUES (
        '$CertificateType',
        '$UserID',  
        '$STCWCode',            
        '$CertNo',          
        '$FromCert',            
        '$ToCert',
        now())";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql3)){
        echo "Resume created successfully.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
}
```

**HTML looks like:**

```
<fieldset class="fieldset-borders">
    <legend>4. Licenses & Certificates</legend>
    <ul class="header"> 
      <li>
        <select id='options' name="CertificateType[]" class="field-style div-format align-left">
          <option selected disabled value="0">Select certificates</option>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
          <option value="3">Three</option>  
        </select>  
      </li>
    </ul>  
    <ul class="cert" id="cert">     
      <li>
        <ul class="column">         
          <li><p class="test-label11">Name</p></li>                     
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="column">         
          <li><p class="test-label11">STCW Code</p></li>                        
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="column">         
          <li><p class="test-label11">Cert. No</p></li>                     
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="column">         
          <li><p class="test-label11">Place of Issue</p></li>                       
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="column">         
          <li><p class="test-label11">Date of Issue</p></li>                        
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="column">         
          <li><p class="test-label11">Date of Expire</p></li>                       
        </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
        <div class="action2" ></div>


</fieldset>
```

**Javascript** code you can check at [**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/re33mkdk/)

I've created [**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/re33mkdk/) to check that part of the form. Have you ideas how to fix It?

Comment: Do you get some error message? Do you have a table that has an auto incremented ID?

Comment: @Jan No, there is no any errors, inserting only first row values. Yes, there is Id - auto increment.

Comment: add to the Php script (error_log("Running");) and check the apache error log file to see how may times you see (Running) in the log

Comment: @Tasos I've tried to use `error_log("Running");`, but nothing happens (nothing printing)

Comment: what os are you running eg linux, windows etc?

Comment: @Tasos windows, why do you asking it?

Comment: because you may be looking at the wrong log -- what are you running, WAMP?

Comment: and check if you enabled error log for php -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230984/error-logging-with-wamp-server-in-php

Comment: Its running on FTP server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use your fiddle JavaScript and add certificate type in hidden field for every row; and name it RowCertificateType same as other fields for row;

```
<input type="hidden" name="RowCertificateType[]" value="" />
<!-- set value of this field same as you are showing in li as label for this row; -->
```

then in your php script use as follows:

```
foreach($_POST['RowCertificateType'] as $key=> $val){

  $CertificateType = $val;

  $STCWCode = $_POST['STCWCode'][$key];
  $CertNo = $_POST['CertNo'][$key];
  $FromCert = $_POST['FromCert'][$key];
  $ToCert = $_POST['ToCert'][$key];

  $CertificateType = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $CertificateType);
  $STCWCode = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $STCWCode);
  $CertNo = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $CertNo);
  $FromCert = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $FromCert);
  $ToCert = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $ToCert);

  $sql3 = "INSERT INTO Tbl (
        CertificateType     
        ,UserId    
        ,STCWCode               
        ,CertNo                 
        ,FromCert               
        ,ToCert
        ,DateCreated
    ) VALUES (
        '$CertificateType',
        '$UserID',  
        '$STCWCode',            
        '$CertNo',          
        '$FromCert',            
        '$ToCert',
        now())";
  if(mysqli_query($link, $sql3)){
    echo "Resume created successfully.";
  }else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
  }
}
```

:)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but with my poor knowledge I can't understand what exactly should I do in *HTML* side, could you provide more information, please?

Comment: [jsfiddle with js changes](https://jsfiddle.net/itzmukeshy7/swz55vth/) anything else?

Comment: Not really understood how, but It worked!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Infinity please tell me what you don't understand.

Answer (score 6):

You need to create forms with this format

```html
<form action="insert.php" method="post">  
<ul>
    <li>
        <input name="CertificateType[0]" type="hidden">
        <input name="CertificateType[0]['STCWCode']" type="text">
        <input name="CertificateType[0]['CertNo']" type="text">
        <input name="CertificateType[0]['PlaceofIssueCert']" type="text">
        <input name="CertificateType[0]['FromCert']" type="date">
        <input name="CertificateType[0]['ToCert']" type="date">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="CertificateType[1]" type="hidden">
        <input name="CertificateType[1]['STCWCode']" type="text">
        <input name="CertificateType[1]['CertNo']" type="text">
        <input name="CertificateType[1]['PlaceofIssueCert']" type="text">
        <input name="CertificateType[1]['FromCert']" type="date">
        <input name="CertificateType[1]['ToCert']" type="date">
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
</form>
```

When you submit form with this format , you will receive **Numeric Key array** in `$_POST['CertificateType']` in insert.php

```
array(
  "0" => array(
           "STCWCode" => "somevalue",
           "CertNo" => "somevalue",
           "PlaceofIssueCert" => "somevalue",
           "FromCert" => "somevalue",
           "ToCert" => "somevalue",  
         ),
  "1" => array(
           "STCWCode" => "somevalue",
           "CertNo" => "somevalue",
           "PlaceofIssueCert" => "somevalue",
           "FromCert" => "somevalue",
           "ToCert" => "somevalue",  
         ),
   . . .
)
```

Here each index will represent one row.This can be retrived using foreach loop as below :

Update your php code as

```
foreach($_POST['CertificateType'] as $val){ 

$CertificateType = $val;

$CertificateType = $val; 
$STCWCode        = $val['STCWCode'];            
$CertNo          = $val['CertNo'];          
$FromCert        = $val['FromCert'];            
$ToCert          = $val['ToCert'];  

$CertificateType = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $CertificateType);  
$STCWCode        = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $STCWCode);                 
$CertNo          = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $CertNo);           
$FromCert        = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $FromCert);                 
$ToCert          = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $ToCert);      

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO Tbl (
    CertificateType     
    ,UserId    
    ,STCWCode               
    ,CertNo                 
    ,FromCert               
    ,ToCert
    ,DateCreated
) VALUES (
    '$CertificateType',
    '$UserID',  
    '$STCWCode',            
    '$CertNo',          
    '$FromCert',            
    '$ToCert',
    now())";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql3)){
    echo "Resume created successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer in terms of technical code but you should explain why they should change it to this format i understand the OP might not.

Comment: Thank you @MartinBarker . I will try to explain in edit.

Comment: @Hirenpatel thank you for your answer, but there could be added rows like 100 or more, so I need repeat It `<input name="CertificateType[0]" type="hidden">`, `<input name="CertificateType[1]" type="hidden">`
up to 100 times? And what will happen If user will add 101 row? It will crash... There is no any dynamic way to achieve It or I misunderstood something?

Comment: you need to create this type of form using the jquery code you are using. you dont need to create every `<input name="CertificateType[0]" type="hidden">` manually . you can modify your jquery to generate form in this format. If you add 100 rows ,On server side you will get one array containing 100 rows (index from 0 to 99). you can traverse it using foreach loop. As here it will be numeric key array , so it will make it easy to loop through. How can you say , it will crash ? @Infinity

Comment: In the Question itself , your approach is to to get multiple `CertificateType`  in post request. Using your approach , Number of time your foreach loop traverse , it will hit database. I would suggest , not to use insert query in forloop. Instead of , Use PDO http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp

Answer (score 3):

See, what i found is:

1. First, Replace `CertificateType[]` with `CertificateType` in `<select id='options' name="CertificateType[]" class="field-style div-format align-left">`
   Because, this dropdown is not multiple. On based upon `onchange` functionality only you are getiing `STCWCode`, `CertNo`, `FromCert` & `ToCert` values, which are multiple (Not `CertificateType` dropdown). 
   **What you can do is:** you can append one `hidden text` namely `CertificateTypeHidden[]` in which value of `CertificateType` dropdown will get inserted.
2. As i pointed in Ist Point. `CertificateType` is not multiple. So, it's considering only one value. What you can do is : As i wrote above, instead of `CertificateType`, you can use `CertificateTypeHidden[]` Like `foreach($_POST['CertificateTypeHidden'] as $key => $val){`.

After Changes, code should look like this way. (If you follow above points)

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['CertificateTypeHidden'] as $key => $val){ 
  $CertificateType = $_POST['CertificateTypeHidden'][$key]; 
  $STCWCode        = $_POST['STCWCode'][$key];  
  $CertNo          = $_POST['CertNo'][$key];   
  $FromCert        = $_POST['FromCert'][$key];   
  $ToCert          = $_POST['ToCert'][$key];  
    .
    .
    .
}
?>
```

For my **testing purpose**. I removed `foreach($_POST['CertificateType'] as $key => $val){` with `foreach($_POST['STCWCode'] as $key => $val){`. All appended multiple textbox values coming correctly.

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['STCWCode'] as $key => $val){ 
  $CertificateType = $_POST['CertificateTypeHidden'][$key]; 
  $STCWCode        = $_POST['STCWCode'][$key];  
  $CertNo          = $_POST['CertNo'][$key];   
  $FromCert        = $_POST['FromCert'][$key];   
  $ToCert          = $_POST['ToCert'][$key];  
    .
    .
    .
}
?>
```

This is the only issue. All well. Just append one hidden field. (`<input type='hidden' name='CertificateTypeHidden[]'>`). In which values of selected dropdown come and sit in `value` attribute of this hidden field. In submit page or **insert.php** page, do `foreach` using `CertificateTypeHidden`.

Go through it. All the best.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, It looks like detailed, but still I can't achieve correctly with HTML side, could you show me how HTML side should look like?

Comment: See, frankly speaking. I tried your code in my system & I was literally trying to add one more textbox for certificate type. But, i was unable to understand jsfiddle code which you provided from your end. Since, this code is of yours, so it will be easy for you. Just be calm and do what i say. As soon you select CertificateType dropdown. New row comes with textbox. So, you just need to add one hidden field namely `CertificateTypeHidden` where that selected dropdown value will come & sit. And, nothing to do more. After that my code will work. I'm 100% sure. *If any doubt, Feel Free To Ask* @Inf

Answer (score 2):

you loop over $_POST['CertificateType'], which (with your configuration) will only contain one value (no multiselect on the select field)

Answer (score 2):

You are using whole wrong loop. Instead you need to run loop over for example `STCWCode` POST variable.

But yet I would suggest you to change javascript code, and make input names something as this  `row[0][STCWCode], row[0][CertNo]` and so on where `row[0]` is for first row and `row[1]` will be for second row and so on. Then you can run loop with `$_POST['row']`

Answer (score 2):

You need create a hidden input with selected value for certificate, the dropdown is only to create the new row but you need create a new input with Array form, maybe change the dropdown name for example CertificateType[] => CertificateTypeList and the new hidden input name with CertificateType[]

UL is not send with the forms only input types.

```
<select id='options' name="CertificateList">
  <option selected disabled value="0">Select certificates</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>  
</select>
```

Create the form tag just once and the inputs for each repetition

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">  
<ul>
    <li>
        <input name="CertificateType[]" type="hidden">
        <input name="STCWCode[]" type="text">
        <input name="CertNo[]" type="text">
        <input name="PlaceofIssueCert[]" type="text">
        <input name="FromCert[]" type="date">
        <input name="ToCert[]" type="date">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="CertificateType[]" type="hidden">
        <input name="STCWCode[]" type="text">
        <input name="CertNo[]" type="text">
        <input name="PlaceofIssueCert[]" type="text">
        <input name="FromCert[]" type="date">
        <input name="ToCert[]" type="date">
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at everything yet but your input fields all seem to have the same name in the fiddle.

The first input of all the rows seem to be "name="STCWCode[]". Have you looked at your $_POST and verified that you can see all your input or if there is just input from the first row? I think the names might be an issue.

Comment: I don't think that's problem with name, here is used arrays, as I know It should work....

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to insert whole array in a single code. First take the count. And then fetch the contents from array and using a for loop insert it into database
for example if my name for the textbox is  `cellname[]`

then for insert this should be done

```
 $itemCount = count($_POST['cellname']);
 $info=$_POST['cellname'];
 for($i=0;$i<$itemCount;$i++) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO item (item_name) VALUES('$info[$i]') ";
  //rest of the queries
 }
```

`